# Border Radius Bug in Chrome Browser on Element with Display:Table

Tags: css

I have bug with border radius in chrome browser.
An element that is styled with border-style dashed property and border-radius and as  display:table;, The background-color exceeds the limit of the border.

How it looks in chrome:

[image]

[Live link: Chrome dashed border-radius issue](http://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/Cxajw)

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need `display:table`?

Comment: If you absolutely need `display:table` then add `display:table-cell` to `.dashed`

Comment: I need this for centering both vertical and horizontal ,if I change the display to table-cell the effect of centering is gone - like in this example -  http://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/Cxajw

Answer (score 1):

Add background-clip: padding-box; to your .box class

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nBzye

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fbackground-clip

Comment: But i need the background-color on the borders to.(As it is display on safari and IE9/IE10)

Comment: is there an absolute need for display: table ?

Comment: Yes, is the easiest way I found for centering horizontal and vertical inner content of 2 rows. If I wont find a solution i will add another wrapper to solve this issue. And I really prefer to solve it without another unneccery elemente